# Google Earth plugin balloon text not showing in Qt QWebView

Tags: qtwebkit, google-earth-plugin, qwebview

I have managed to get the standard Qt 4.7.4 QWebView demo to work with the Google Earth Plugin by overriding the userAgentForUrl() method. However, pointing the browser to the standard Google Earth Code Playground I notice that none of the placemark balloons display any text. It looks like a WebKit problem? Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post some example code or link to an example, screen shot, etc?